# NullPointerException - What to do?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, togglebutton

I'm experiencing a NullpointerException with this code:

```
kuglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(toggle.isChecked())
            {                   
                counter1 = counter1 + 10;
                column1tv.setText("" + counter1);                   
            }
            else
            {           
                counter1 = counter1 - 2;
                column1tv.setText("" + counter1);           
            }
        }                   
});
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong, and maybe how to fix it?

Comment: kuglebutton or toogle or column1tv is null.

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace of the exception and see which lin eof code generated it

Comment: Keep that in try catch and post the Exception which u are getting ??

Comment: Put Logacat,Your Full code....

Comment: -1 for lack of information and research effort. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: where did u getting Exception. At Which statement u getting....?

Comment: -1 for not responding to any of the above comments

Answer (score 0):

As blackbelt said, something is null. Use logcat to see exactly where you get the exception. When you found the place, the problem is sometimes obvious.